# ActiveMQ resumes queue automatically on restart

Tags: spring-boot, jms, activemq-artemis

I am using ActiveMQ Artemis latest version. I have a queue which is currently in the paused state. I am pausing it using the `pause()` command via UI console, Queue Operations. When I restart the server the queue becomes active and starts delivering messages. Is there any way in which I can persist the paused state of queue between restarts?

Comment: @JustinBertram Active MQ Artemis Latest version, pausing it using pause() command via UI console, Queue Operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `pause(boolean)` operation instead of the plain `pause()` operation. The `boolean` indicates whether or not the pausing should be persisted. So ultimately you'd use `pause(true)`.

[image]